# EF Core HasDiscriminator with nullable discriminator

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to specify that I already have a discriminator on the entity, but am not sure how to represent it here.

The discriminator between them is whether or not a column is null. Obviously the case where it is null I can just put that explicitly, but what do I do for the case where its not?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    modelBuilder.Entity<Schedule>()
        .HasDiscriminator<Guid?>("ManagerId")
        .HasValue<EmployeeSchedule>(null)
        .HasValue<ManagerSchedule>(/* What goes here? */);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by putting the property `bool IsManagerSchedule` on `Schedule`, and then using `.HasValue<ManagerSchedule>(true).HasValue<EmployeeSchedule>(false);`.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the manual configuration and then:

```
public class EmployeeSchedule {
    // properties of all employees...
}

public class ManagerSchedule {
    public TYPE PropertyName {get; set;} // discriminator property
}
```